# Past SImple vs Past Continuous

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

While practising past tenses I have encountered a couple of confusing dialogues.

> A: How was your holiday?
>
> B: Awful! It __________ (rain) the whole time.

The key says that the right answer is past simple i.e. "rained", but I tend to use past continuous there to say that an action was in progress at every moment during a period of time.

Could someone clarify I am right or not?

And here's the second one:

> A: Was Jack practising his guitar again last night?
>
> B: Why do you ask?  _________________ (you/try) to call him?

Can I use past continuous there too to say that at the time Jack was practising his guitar, person A was trying to call him (an action in progress at a stated time in past)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are idiomatic and mean much the same thing since rain isn't a discrete, goal-oriented action:

> It rained the whole time.
>
> It was raining the whole time.

With the following example the meaning is slightly different, since a call is a discrete action with a goal that can be attained; it is a completeable action:

> Why do you ask? Were you trying to call him?
>
> Why do you ask? Did you try to call him?

The continuous suggests repeated attempts to reach the person by phone, whereas the simple past suggests a single attempt.